# Let $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function on $\Bbb{R}$ satisfying some properties, prove $f\equiv 0$ a.e.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> Let $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function on $\Bbb{R}$ satisfying:
>
> i) there is $p\in (1,\infty)$ such that $f\in L^p(I)$ for any bounded interval $I$.
>
> ii) there is some $\theta \in (0,1)$ such that: $$\left|\int_I f\ dx\right|^p\leq \theta (\mu(I))^{p-1}\int_I |f|^p\ dx$$
>
> Prove that $f\equiv 0 $ a.e.

This is a [previous qual question](http://www.math.purdue.edu/files/academic/grad/qualexams/MA54400/MA544-aug15.pdf) (3, beware: PDF).

My thoughts.

We assume that there is some $E$ where without loss of generality $f>0$ on $E$ and $\mu(E)>0$. Using regularity of Lebesgue measure, for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some open $G_{\epsilon}$ with $\mu(G_{\epsilon}\setminus E)<\epsilon$ and $E \subseteq G_{\epsilon}$. We may decompose $G_{\epsilon}$ as a countable disjoint union $I_k$. So we must only show that there is a contradiction if $f>0$ on some interval.

I tried arguing like this:

$$\begin{align*}\left|\int_I f\ dx\right|^p&\leq \theta (\mu(I))^{p-1}\int_I |f|^p\ dx\\ &\leq\theta (\mu(I))^{p-1} \mu(I) \operatorname{essup}(|f|^p)\\&=\theta(\mu(I))^p\operatorname{essup}_I(|f|^p)\end{align*}$$

I feel like there should be a general contradiction here (for example if $I=(0,1)$ and $f=1$ this inequality doesn't hold).

Can someone help me? I would like hints only please.

Comment: I don't see why $essup_I(|f|^p)$ is finite? That not holding would neuter this approach, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $\theta = 1/2$ just to scratch around a bit. For $h>0$ we have

$$|\int_a^{a+h} f\,\,|^p \le \frac{1}{2}\cdot h^{p-1}\int_a^{a+h} |f|^p \implies  |\frac{1}{h} \int_a^{a+h} f|^p \le \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h} |f|^p.$$

In the last inequality, let $h\to 0^+$ and apply the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.